# Android studio/IntelliJ import project from svn

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-studio

I have an android studio project that exist in an SVN repository.

How can I access that project and create/sync it to a new local project.

Basically it exists in repository, and now I want open and edit in android studio.

Comment: Did you try "Check out from Version Control" option?

Comment: Studio in this way so complex and unsuable. Even for simple checkout, they ask zillion questions and even after all that the project getting checked out is completely unsuable. stupid Google egoism to get rid of eclipse

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can simply use a SVN client like [tortoise](http://tortoisesvn.net/) to import and sync the project on your PC.

If you want to use IntelliJ built-in SVN client, give a look to the [official guide](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/checking-out-files-from-subversion-repository.html)

Comment: Why do I need to use and enternal svn client when I thought android studio had built in svn functionality.